# Open google play details page for an app via javascript redirect from android browser

Tags: javascript, android, redirect, google-play

I want my website to redirect to a specific app in the Google Play Market if it is opened on an android device. I followed the instructions on http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html:

```
"Display the details screen for a specific application: http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>".
```

Works great with a link the user is actively clicking on:

```
<a href="http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>">Download app</a>
```

But if I am detecting the device with javascript and trying to redirect the browser automatically changes the http://... to https://... and the user is redirected to the Google Play website instead of the Google Play app on the phone.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1) {
    if(confirm("Download app?")) {
        window.location.href= "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>";
    }
}
```

Is there any way to change this behavior, my test device is a Samsung Galaxy with android 2.3.3?

Comment: How about modifying the href of the link (`<a`) from the javascript code rather than setting the window.location.href?

Comment: I tried to trigger a click-event on the link with jquery but it didn't work. How do you mean "modifying the href of the link"? The link itself is working, it is the javascript redirect which causes the android browser to replace http:// with https://

Comment: Just wondering, are you using the default browser or google chrome beta? I added your javascript snippet to a test page - with the default browser on my Galaxy Nexus 4.0.2 it works as you would expect. However using google chrome I'm not given the "Complete action using" option, it just takes me to the website - still looking into it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This seems to work. The redirect opens the Google Play app while using the default browser, but translates the link to https:// play.google... when using chrome

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1) {
    if(confirm("Download app?")) {
        window.location.href= "market://details?id=<packagename>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to **redirect** to **Google Play app** try doing it from the server.

Client side attempts will not work.

PHP example

```
    header("Location: market://details?id=com.your.app");
```

Answer (score 1):

If the accepted answer does not work or fails to open in Chrome with this error

> ERROR: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Change the window.location.href to window.location like this

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1) {
 if(confirm("Download app?")) {
    window.location= "market://details?id=<packagename>";
 }
}
```